# Sound of racing cars passing by at different velocities

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sound

I'm currently trying to generate the sound of racing cars passing by  at different velocities from this single sound of a racing car passing by at a **certain** velocity:

Which tranformations are necessary in order to transform this sound such that it appears like the sound of a racing car at lower or higher speed?

**My ideas:**

Adjust both pitch and playback speed. But this leads to an "artificial" sound, it doesn't sound naturally.

Comment: Couldn't you find one that doesn't sound like he's changing gear as he comes past? That's going to make the job a lot harder.

Comment: That's just an example. I'm interested in how to change the acoustic perception of the speed of a moving object in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have a pitch shifter VST I downloaded this: https://www.kvraudio.com/product/pitcheddelay-by-lkjb

And ended up with this after 10 minutes:

What i did:

- Slowed down the sample 3x because it's too short. Cars don't fade out after 5 seconds.
- Added progressing reverb towards the end of the sample
- To give a sense of acceleration I steadily increased the pitch.
- Decreased the pitch at the time the car passed by.
- Applied some distortion

And I did this for lols, just to show what's possible with a lot less of a sample:

I recommend you get a proper software for doing things like this. http://www.audiomulch.com/info/what-is-audiomulch